# How to optimize my SSD and HDD configuration

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

I have completed my first custom PC build. I installed Windows 8 Pro and I have a few questions pertaining to the OS and the way I should configure my hard discs.

I have a 128 GB SSD that I installed the OS on and I have a 3 TB HDD. I want to reserve as much space as possible on the SSD and limit the use because I know they have a limited life.

**Q:** How would I optimize the life span of my SSD? I wanted to put everything else on the HDD other than the OS of course. Is this the right choice? If so how do I change the settings for Program Files and folders such as *My Documents, Downloads, Pictures* etc. to default to my HDD (E:/ Drive)?

Comment: Your SSD will most likely last longer than your computer will.  Dont believe the paranoia around SSDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't try this, this will only cause issues when installing updates. Run Windows as it is. Modern SSDs are so solid that you can write 10GB of data daily for 10 years before they fail.

Comment: Thank You for the information. I guess I was just so paranoid about prolonging the life of my SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Basic SSD configuration

```
disable file indexing
disable defragment
```

No need for file indexing and defragmentation, SSD random access is that fast

If you want, there is always [something more to tweak](http://thessdreview.com/ssd-guides/optimization-guides/the-ssd-optimization-guide-ultimate-windows-8-edition/).

Unless you use it 24/7, making builds or other hard intensive work, you will change the SSD at the same time with your computer: too old, need a new one.

Comment: Actually you don't have to *disable* defragment task since Windows 7/8 will do this automatically if it detects a SSD as OS drive