# What's the best way to use both an SSD and an HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, cache

I have a Windows 7 laptop with an 128GB SSD and an 1TB HDD. I want to use both efficiently. I have 2 plans so far.

Plan A) Use 50GB of SSD for OS. Use the rest of SSD as a cache space to boost an HDD using a caching software like eBoostr, PrimoCache, etc. Aiming for automatic cache(hit rate) management.

Plan B) Use 50GB of SSD for OS. Use the rest of SSD for crucial or frequently loaded programs like anti-virus, web browsers, some games, etc. Use HDD as a storage for games, media, docs, etc. Manual management and changing usage frequency might be problems.

What should I choose? Or are there any better ideas?

Comment: Super user is full of these questions. Google "ssd hdd site:superuser.com"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to optimize my SSD and HDD configuration](http://superuser.com/questions/632460/how-to-optimize-my-ssd-and-hdd-configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  prefer Plan B, without partitioning the SSD. I install all my softwares and games to ssd and use hdd for storing movies, music, docs etc.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. But can I get some reasons for choosing Plan B and not choosing Plan A?

Comment: softwares like eboostr improves performance by caching. But why waste around 70 gb just for caching. According to my usage pattern for the programs that I use 128 gb is more than enough. I use visual studio, couple of games, other softwares like browsers, antivirus etc and still I have around 30 gb free space. I use my HDD only for storing data that I do not use frequently. So I don't see any significant performance boost by caching contents of hdd.